# Infinite geometric series whose coefficients correspond to the number of solutions of a Diophantine equation.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, diophantine-equations

This is problem 2 from Polya's Problems and Theorems in Analysis I. The question is as follows,

Let $A_n$ denote the number of solutions to the Diophantine equation $x+5y+10z+25u+50v=n$. What is the rational function of $\zeta$ represented by the series $A_0+A_1\zeta+A_2\zeta^2+\dots+A_n\zeta^n+\dots$ ?

I own the book so I have the solution in the back, but how would I derive it? Is there a place on the internet where I can familiarize myself with infinite series that correspond to the solutions of Diophantine equations?

Answer (score 0):

Let's work out a smaller example. Let $B_n$ represent the number of solutions of $x + 5y = n$. Consider

$$ f(\zeta) = (1 + \zeta + \zeta^2 + ...)(1 + (\zeta^5) + (\zeta^5)^2 + ...)$$

Perform the multiplication to see that a coefficient at $\zeta^n$ is $B_n$. Calculate both factors as geometrical series to obtain a rational function. Apply the same logic to an original equation.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. In case anyone wants to know more. I found an article about this problem from the author himself (Polya) written in American Math Monthly Vol. 63 Number 10.